# How to get javascript value to rails variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a two partial forms

1. _slider.html.erb
2. _form.html.erb

_form.html.erb is embedding the _slider.html.erb, which contains a javascript slider value as below;

```
onChange: function(v)
  {  $('slide').value= v; }
```

My question is: how can I get the 'slide' value from _slider.html.erb to a rails variable in the _form.html.erb file so that I can post that value using

```
<%= number_field :score, :obtained_score, :value => **that variable** %>
```

to my database?

Answer (score 0):

Wording of your question needs a change because you will not be copying javascript variable to rails variable but everything will be happening on client side meaning it is all javascript only.

onchange event of the slider should update `<input id='model_score' type='number' />` element from DOM generated by rails with following code

```
<%= number_field :score, :obtained_score, :value => that variable %>
```

In onchange handler for slider do following

```
on_slider_change_handler = function(e){
  $("#model_score").value = $(this).value; // this will be slider specific code
};
```

Comment: Tks Amitamb, ur answer is fine, but my question is 'how to store that slider change value to a "rails variable"'.
Bcoz I need to store that value to my sqlite3 database.

the below code is also working fine, it displays the current value in the text_filed..
onChange: function(v)
  {  $('slide').value= v; }

<%= text_field_tag :slide %>
will display the current slide value.